# Perform CRUD in controller with ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

From my two models `Student` and `InventoryRecord`. I created a ViewModel named `TestViewModel`. I'm confused as to how do I write my controller?

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    //from Student model
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber{ get; set; }
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    //other properties

    //from Inventory model
    public string FathersName { get; set; }
    public string FathersAddress { get; set; }
    //other properties

}
```

When I'm using only my main model `Student`. This is how I write my controller:

```
// GET: Students/CreateEdit
    public ActionResult InventoryRecord()
    {
        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var newid = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserID == currentUserId);

        if (newid == null)
        {
            newid = db.Students.Create();
            newid.UserID = currentUserId;
            db.Students.Add(newid);

        }

        Student student = db.Students.Find(newid.UserID);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(student);
    }

    // POST: Students/CreateEdit
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult InventoryRecord(Student student)
    {

        var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var userName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        var u = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserID == currentUserId);

        if (u == null)
        {
            u = db.Students.Create();
            u.UserID = currentUserId;
            db.Students.Add(u);

        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            u.PhoneNumber = student.PhoneNumber;
            u.Address = student.Address;
            //other properties

            db.SaveChanges();

            TempData["Message"] = "User: " + userName + ", details successfully updated!";
        }

        return View(student);
    }
```

Now, I'm really confused how to proceed here. How should I write my controller if I'm using my `TestViewModel`? Someone please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: First remove the `[Key]` attribute (that is related to EF,  not view models). In your POST method you initialize new instances of you data models (or if your editong existng data, then you get the data models from the database based on the ID), and set their properties based on the values in the view models, then save the data models.

Comment: In your POST method you should to create a instance object of TestViewModel and fill it  with posted data in your action..That is all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well personally I would move the code out of the controller.

However for example you just need to create an instance of your `TestViewModel` and pass that to your view. You may also need to update your View if you specific the model in the cshtml.

```
public ActionResult InventoryRecord()
{
    var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var newid = db.Students.FirstOrDefault(d => d.UserID == currentUserId);

    if (newid == null)
    {
        newid = db.Students.Create();
        newid.UserID = currentUserId;
        db.Students.Add(newid);

    }

    Student student = db.Students.Find(newid.UserID);
    if (student == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    TestViewModel model = new TestViewModel
    {
        UserID = student.UserId,
        PhoneNumber = student.PhoneNumber,
        //add the rest.
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning Student , return TestViewModel

```
    Student student = db.Students.Find(newid.UserID);
    if (student == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    TestViewModel tvm = new TestViewModel()
    {
        UserID =student.Id,
        PhoneNumber = student.PhoneNumber,
        Address= student.Address
    };

    return View(tvm);
 }
```

and second method will be

```
 public ActionResult InventoryRecord(TestViewModel tvm)
```